# React Router - Browser History needs a dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, react-router, material-ui

I am using React.js and express for my app. I am trying to set-up react-router-dom for the app.

However, when I try to run the app, I get the warning:

```js
Invariant Violation: Browser history needs a DOM
    at invariant (/home/jshen/playlistTracker/node_modules/invariant/invariant.js:40:15)
    at createBrowserHistory (/home/jshen/playlistTracker/node_modules/history/createBrowserHistory.js:49:27)
    at new BrowserRouter (/home/jshen/playlistTracker/node_modules/react-router-dom/BrowserRouter.js:46:197)
    at processChild (/home/jshen/playlistTracker/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:2095:14)
    at resolve (/home/jshen/playlistTracker/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:2061:5)
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.render (/home/jshen/playlistTracker/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:2380:22)
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.read (/home/jshen/playlistTracker/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:2354:19)
    at renderToString (/home/jshen/playlistTracker/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:2726:25)
    at handleRender (/home/jshen/playlistTracker/dist/server.js:755:41)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/jshen/playlistTracker/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/jshen/playlistTracker/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /home/jshen/playlistTracker/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/jshen/playlistTracker/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/jshen/playlistTracker/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at expressInit (/home/jshen/playlistTracker/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/init.js:40:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/jshen/playlistTracker/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

**App.jsx**

```js
import React, {Component, Fragment} from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { NavBar } from './layouts'
import Main from './main'


class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentUser: {name: "testUser"},
      favourite: [],
      playlist: []
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <NavBar>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path ="/" render={
              () => <div> hello </div>
            }/>
          </Switch>
        </NavBar>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }

}

export default App;
```

**server.js**

```js
import express from 'express';
import React from 'react';
import App from '../client/App.jsx';

import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'
import { SheetsRegistry } from 'react-jss/lib/jss'
import JssProvider from 'react-jss/lib/JssProvider'
import {
  MuiThemeProvider,
  createMuiTheme,
  createGenerateClassName,
} from '@material-ui/core/styles'

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// This is fired every time the server side receives a request.
app.use(handleRender);
app.listen(port);

// inject our initial component HTML and CSS into a template to be rendered on the client side.
function renderFullPage(html, css) {
  return `
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Material-UI</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="root">${html}</div>
        <style id="jss-server-side">${css}</style>
      </body>
    </html>
  `;
}

// When rendering, we will wrap App, our root component, inside a JssProvider and MuiThemeProvider 
// to make the sheetsRegistry and the theme available to all components in the component tree.
// Render the initial HTML of our component before we send it to the client side. 
// To do this, we use ReactDOMServer.renderToString().
function handleRender(req, res) {
  // Create a sheetsRegistry instance.
  const sheetsRegistry = new SheetsRegistry();

  // Create a theme instance.
  const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
      primary: {
        light: '#757575',
        main: '#a4a4a4',
        dark: '#494949',
        contrastText: '#ffffff',
      },
      secondary: {
        light: '#263238',
        main: '#a4a4a4',
        dark: '#494949',
        contrastText: '#ffffff',
      },
      // accent: red,
      // type: 'light',
    },
  });

  const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName();

  // Render the component to a string.
  const html = renderToString(
    <JssProvider registry={sheetsRegistry} generateClassName={generateClassName}>
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme} sheetsManager={new Map()}>
        <App />
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    </JssProvider>
  )

  // Grab the CSS from our sheetsRegistry.
  const css = sheetsRegistry.toString()

  // Send the rendered page back to the client.
  res.send(renderFullPage(html, css))
}
```

Couldn't figure out what I'm missing. I think it may be due to something on the server side but couldnt figure out.

I have read that it may be due to the history component However, I have seen examples of it working with just BrowerRouter.(e.g. https://github.com/jsmegatools/React-online-course/tree/master/Lesson-2)

Thanks!

Comment: You are not supposed to import and use the `BrowserRouter` on the server, since there is no DOM on the server. [This guide might give some inspiration](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/server-rendering).

Comment: @Tholle, thanks! The guide helped me alot

Answer (score 0):

You need to set it up correctly. Both of them are different each other. React is client side app, while Express is a server app.

Have a look at [Sandeep Raveesh's post](https://hackernoon.com/full-stack-web-application-using-react-node-js-express-and-webpack-97dbd5b9d708), and try the [boilerplate](https://github.com/crsandeep/simple-react-full-stack). It might help you to understand it.

Comment: I'd recommend putting the relevant snippets in the answer or it'll get flagged as a link-only answer, which will get deleted.

Comment: Got it. Thanks dude.

Answer (score 0):

@Tholle 's answer helped me solve the problem.

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/server-rendering